# LUA: Como chamar uma function dentro do loop e não pausar-lo

Tags: lua

estou enfrentando um problema em um código que estou a fazer e pelo fato de ter aprendido por mim mesmo e *na marra* não estou sabendo lidar com este problema.

Tudo acontece porque quero chamar uma função e continuar o *mainloop*, porém assim que eu chamo a function inDeath() o mainloop **para** e aguarda um break/return da function que foi chamada.

Logo, minha dúvida é: há como chamar uma function e continuar o loop(que a chamou) sem esperar um return/break?

```lua
local isworking = false

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(100)
        print("RUNNING") -- tá rodando? Está
        if not isworking then
        isworking = true
        local ped = PlayerPedId() -- Entidade
           if GetEntityHealth(ped) <= 101 then -- Vida da entidade
              inDeath() -- função a ser chamada
           end
        end
        --[[RESTANTE DO CÓDIGO]]
    end
end)

function inDeath()
    local ped = PlayerPedId() -- Entidade
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(1)
        if GetEntityHealth(ped) > 399 then -- Vida da entidade
            isworking = false
            break --stop function
        end
          --[[RESTANTE DO CÓDIGO/FUNCTION]]
    end
end
```

Comment: Aprenda sobre corotinas em Lua